# Cannot shutdown WildFly 9.0.2.Final on Windows 10

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-9

I have a WildFly 9.0.2.Final server running on windows 10.
When I try shutdown the server using command:

```
jboss-cli.bat --connect command=:shutdown
```

I see the following log:
**Failed to connect to the controller: The controller is not available at localhost:9990: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://localhost:9990. The connection failed: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://localhost:9990. The connection failed: Invalid response**
What this means and how can I shutdown the server?

Comment: May be you start WildFly with -b option and bind to other address? jbocc-cli by default connection to host specified in jboss-cli.xml

Comment: I found the problem. Nvidia service has the same port. 
Аfter I killed Nvidia process it worked fine.

Comment: How do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This means your management controller is not listening to the `localhost:9990`
Possible reasons could be that you `jboss` didn't started properly i.e. management console itself is down

or

It's not bind to all IPv4 address
For this try starting with `-bmanagement`

```
./standalone.sh -c standalone-ha.xml -b <your ip> -bmanagement <your ip>
```